# How to get updated document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I updated document and I need a updated document

```
const updateMe = await Friends.updateOne(
      {
        userId: req.user._id,
        "friends._id": req.params.id,
      },
      {
        $set: { "friends.$.status": "added" },
      },
      { returnDocument: "after" }
    );
    console.log(updateMe);
```

But it s returning that

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

How can I get it?

Comment: The response from the database indicated that this particular execution didn't find any matching documents to modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use findOneAndUpdate because it has the option to get the updated document.

Example from mongo docs

```
db.students2.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id : 1 },
   [ { $set: { "total" : { $sum: "$grades.grade" } } } ],  // The $set stage is 
     an alias for ``$addFields`` stage
   { returnNewDocument: true }
)
```

[MongoDb findOneAndUpdate Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)